# Is position of equilibrium path independent?

Tags: equilibrium

I know that if a reaction is at equilibrium, then  changes in condition may change the position of equilibrium and the direction is such shift can be predicted by Le Chatlier's rule. But now we're studying the Haber process and my teacher applied this rule to two reactions happening at different pressures in two different containers (initial amounts added, temp were kept constant for both) . Can Le Chatlier's be used this way? I understand the idea that increasing the pressure will lead to a relatively higher mole fractions of the products in the Haber reaction ( I got this using Kp) but don't see how this is a consequence of Le Chatlier.

So basically, will the position of equilibrium be the same if I let my system come to equilibrium at a pressure A and then increase it to B or if I directly come to B?

Comment: If the position of equilibrium were path-dependent, you'd be able to build a perpetual motion machine out of it.

Comment: @Ivan, could you please elaborate?

Comment: What's the point? You won't build it anyway.

Comment: @Ivan, haha no I won't but I'd like to know why position of equilibria must be path independent.

Comment: If it was not independent, you could create energy by cyclical travelling between 2 states via 2 different paths.